# Centralizer of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ as subalgebra of $\mathfrak{sl}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I am trying to find the centralizer $C(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ of $\mathfrak{sl}_2 = \textrm{span}\{H^1, E^1_{\pm}\}$ in $\mathfrak{sl}_3$, but I don't know how to do this.

My first guess was to show that $x \in  C(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ implies that $[x, H^1] = 0$ and $[x, E^1_{\pm}] = 0$, so that we can find the centralisers of these two elements and take the intersection.

But doing this, I see that the first centralizer is given by $\textrm{span}\{H^1, H^2\}$ and the second one by $\textrm{span}\{E^1_{\pm}, E^2_{\mp}, E^{\theta}_{\pm}\}$. The intersections of these two appear to be only $\{0\}$, but I think there should be some elements in there.

Comment: As Dietrich Burde's answer shows, your computation of  the second centraliser must be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The centralizer is contained in the $2$-dimensional Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{sl}(3)$. Then a computation with explicit basis elements shows that it is $1$-dimensional.
Indeed, let
$$
 (e_1,\ldots ,e_8)=(E_{12}, E_{13}, E_{21}, E_{23}, E_{31}, E_{32}, E_{11}-E_{22},E_{22}-E_{33})
$$
be a canonical basis for $\mathfrak{sl}(3)$ and take
$\mathfrak{sl}(2)=\langle e_1,e_3,e_7\rangle$, then
$$
C_{\mathfrak{sl}(3)}(\mathfrak{sl}(2))=\langle e_7+2e_8\rangle.
$$